# How to perform addition of numbers using threads in Java using executor framework?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I was wondering can I use multi-threading to add 10 number but points to consider are below:

1. I want to group numbers like (1,2)(3,4)(5,6).... and perform addition in separate threads.
2. Using executors `future.get` method get the result and again group the result e.g. (1,2) gives 3 and (3,4) gives 7 so now I want these two result to group and pass to another thread for addition (3,7)
3. Repeat the same process until I get the single number which would be the result.

I am halfway through but don't know how to proceed ahead also I am not sure is the remaining part which is grouping and adding of the result is possible or not.

```
public class CallableAdder implements Callable<Integer> {

Integer operand1;
Integer operand2;
CallableAdder(Integer operand1,Integer operand2)
{
    this.operand1=operand1;
    this.operand2=operand2;

}

public Integer call() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" says : partial Sum for " + operand1 + " and "+ operand2+ " is "  +(operand1+operand2));
    return operand1+operand2;
}

}
```

Another class :

```
public class ParallelAdder {
public Integer parallelSum()
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List <Future<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();
    int prev=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)         //grouping
        {
            System.out.println("Prev :" + prev + " current: " + i);
            Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(new CallableAdder(prev,i));
            list.add(future);
            continue;
        }
        prev=i;
    }
    int totsum=0;
    for(Future<Integer> fut : list)
    {
        try {
            totsum = totsum+ fut.get();  
   //This contains result from first iteration here I have added everything 
   //but what I wanted to do is create another thread and perform the same 
   //operation as I did before group and then add meaning repeating step 1 and 2
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Total Sum is " + totsum);
    return totsum;   
}

public int sequentialSum()
{

    Integer totsum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        totsum=totsum+i;
    }
    System.out.println("sequentialSum Total Sum is " + totsum);
    return totsum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ParallelAdder adder = new ParallelAdder();
    int pSum= adder.parallelSum();
    int sSum= adder.sequentialSum();

    System.out.println("parallel Sum equals to Sequential Sum ? " );
    System.out.println("Answer is :: "  + (pSum==sSum));

}
}
```

Please take a look and help me out with the further code.

Comment: Look into `ForkJoinPool`, this is exactly for these purposes.

Comment: @HenriViik Sure will look into that Thanks.